Monthly Topic Challenge – Propose and vote for topics here!
This is a quick way to expand the scope of the site and generate new questions and answers.
How it works: One topic will be designated each week starting Friday 0:00 and ending Thursday 23:59 (CET). The current topic is listed below.
How to enter:
In order to participate, simply ask a question about the topic and tag your question with the topic's tag.
The winning question will be determined by the amount of upvotes the question garners. In the case of a tie, view count will be used. Your question must not be closed and/or deleted in order to qualify. Your question must be asked within the promotion week.
This is all well and good, but what do I get from this? - Honestly, at the moment, nothing.  There are no prizes as we are a Beta site and do not have the financial backing of StackExchange at all for contests.  This is purely maintained by the moderators with user input as to what the topics should be.  That doesn't mean, however, that this is all for naught.  As stated, this is an effort to improve the traffic, visibility, and overall quality of the site.
Choosing the topic of the week: If you have suggestions for a future topic, please leave them as answers to this post. Topics must be trackable with a tag, meaning that specific events, software, proposals, services, concepts, and altcoins are encouraged. Basically anything that currently has a tag is probably fair game. Topics will be chosen based on either their timely and increased notoriety or to expand the Bitcoin.SE's content and scope.

Next topic:

Previous topics:

bip347-op-cat 2024-08-01 – 2024-08-08 – Four questions asked and answered
lightning-dev-kit 2023-01-04 – 2022-01-10 – No questions or answers posted
replace-by-fee 2022-12-08 – 2022-12-14 – Two questions asked, five answers received, 20+ posts edited
scalability 2016-12-02 – 2016-12-08 – No questions survived.
tumblebit 2016-11-25 – 2016-12-01 – One question asked!
version-bits 2016-11-18 – 2016-11-24: No questions asked!
mimblewimble 2016-11-11 – 2016-11-17: Two questions asked!
replace-by-fee 2016-11-04 – 2016-11-10: One question asked!
zcash 2016-10-28 – 2016-11-03: Three questions asked!
segregated-witness 2016-10-21 – 2016-10-27: Five questions asked!


[Credit to Brett White and Movies.SE from whose templates I have shamelessly copied.]

I really like asking zcash questions. Should I hold them back till next week? :-)

@5chdn: Well, since there is nothing to be won in the challenge except eternal glory, you really don't have to. ;) … but either way you could help by starting to add content to the tag-wiki. ;)

Maybe, changing this to a monthly topic challenge is a good idea as more questions about the chosen topic can be accumulated and the chosen topics are higher-quality as fewer have to be found.

@UTF-8: Monthly seems pretty long, but perhaps fortnightly would be better. However, I've discontinued posing new challenges of the week, because a) either the topics I've picked were not interesting, or b) the challenge is of little interest in general, and c) no additional topics were proposed. –– I.e. if you have some ideas, drop a note! :)

zcash is launching on Oct-28, so I'm totally supporting the weekly challenge for Zcash for next week.

Yeah, that was my reason that I had put it directly on the list.

Yes good timing. I predict a lot of people with Zcash questions next week!

@2quick4u: Less than I thought. ;)

Segregated Witness will deliver the last prerequisite for beta versions of lightning-network to go live on the mainnet. Perhaps now would be a good time to ask and learn more about it. 

I'd be happy to try to answer lightning-development-kit questions as they arise.

By the way, how do I make something a link to a non-meta tag?

You can make a link using [tag:<tagname>]

Aiming to use this for the topic week in January 2023

The development of username/password-less accounts seem to be the next big thing in terms of account security, developers ease of integration, and end-user ease-of-use.
We should discuss this topic as a community to help further develop specifications, especially as related to Token Controlled Access (referred to as TCA).
I myself am working on a Bitcoin implementation, named Authparty at its core with the ability for Counterparty users to deploy custom identity tokens. This open source service acts as a broker, or passport, to TCA services base on one proof of address ownership.

Hey, thanks for proposing a topic. Could you please propose a tag for this challenge? I've also not seen this topic discussed lately, what makes you think it's the next big thing?

Tumblebit seems to be an interesting concept that has gotten some attention since Scaling Bitcoin. It might make an interesting topic of the week.
